# How to sync between [plot reloadData] and annotation in core plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, graph, core-plot

[image]
[image]

My requirement is, on dragging the vertical line - it should slide along with the < > arrow buttons.The view at the right end becomes of green transparent.
My issue is,sometimes when I drag the vertical line ,the line,buttons are mis aligned as shown in picture 2.Could anyone help to resolve my issue.

Implementation of plot line drag event.`enter code here`

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
CPTScatterPlot *freqRolPlot = (CPTScatterPlot *)[self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph plotAtIndex:2];

        CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph convertPoint:point toLayer:self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame];
        NSInteger indexVal = [thePlot indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint:pointInPlotArea];
        if(pointInPlotArea.x <=24)
        {
            indexVal = 0;
            pointInPlotArea.x = 14.0f;
        }
        NSDictionary* num = [self.editableGraphData objectAtIndex:indexVal];

        if(pointInPlotArea.x <=24)
        {
            freqRollCoordinate = 20;
        }
        else{
            freqRollCoordinate = [[num objectForKey:@"x"] integerValue];
        }

        [self showDisabledView:pointInPlotArea.x];
        [self showFreqRolAnnotation:freqRollCoordinate:pointInPlotArea.x];
        [freqRolPlot reloadData];
return YES;
}



-(void)showDisabledView:(float)selectedAreaXPos
{

    CPTGraph *graph = self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph;
    if (self.maskAnnotation ) {
        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:self.maskAnnotation];
        self.maskAnnotation = nil;
        [nxtBtn removeFromSuperview];
        [prevBtn removeFromSuperview];
    }

    prevBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    prevBtn.frame = CGRectMake(selectedAreaXPos-7,18,30,30);
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PrevbtnImg"];
    [prevBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    nxtBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    nxtBtn.frame = CGRectMake(3,15,30,30);
    UIImage *nxtImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NextbtnImg"];
    [nxtBtn setImage:nxtImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(selectedAreaXPos,0,self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph.bounds.size.width-selectedAreaXPos,self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph.bounds.size.height);
    CPTBorderedLayer * imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];

    CPTColor *transparentGreen = [[CPTColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.4)];
    CPTFill* areaFill = [[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:transparentGreen];
    imageLayer.fill = areaFill;

    [imageLayer addSublayer:nxtBtn.layer];

    self.maskAnnotation =[[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:nil];
    self.maskAnnotation.contentLayer = imageLayer;

    [graph addSublayer:prevBtn.layer];
    [self.curveEditingGraphView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:self.maskAnnotation];
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the `anchorPlotPoint` for the plot space annotation? Why do you create a new annotation and all of its pieces on every drag event? It would give much better performance to create it once and only update the `anchorPlotPoint` during the drag event.

Comment: @EricSkroch Thank You, I will update it accordingly.U mean by updating anchorPlotPoint for annotation in drag event ,I could resolve my issue ?I mean syncing the movement of Plot(vertical line) and annotation.

Comment: I think it might, but it's hard to tell since you don't show where it is done now. It would certainly improve performance and remove any resulting lag in drawing the new positions.